# upload library is not loading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

upload library is not loading..need help its urjent.

is this is correct or i did anything wrong in this code

```
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH .'products';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size']    = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    if($this->load->library('Upload',$config)){
    echo 'Loaded !';
    }else{
    echo 'Unable to load';
```

i dont know why upload library not loading

advanced thanks

Comment: Did you read the manual on how to call the upload class? Why are you checking `$this->load->library()` ?

Comment: This function returns no value I think your library is probably loaded please try uploading the file one more thing if you want to set your settings then use like

$this->load->library('Upload',$config);

Comment: yes i tried in your way like  $this->load->library('Upload',$config) still am getting same error

Comment: See this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html may be its help you

Comment: no use kruti i tried it

Comment: Do you have permissions set correctly on your upload folder? this is a very good tutorial   http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation/ Also if you scroll down there are ALOT of comments with code etc

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$this->load->library('Upload',$config)
```

This is 100% wrong. look at the manual again.

You don't check if the library is loaded, you check if the class function do_upload() is successful

So,
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){ ... fail }

Just like it says here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

It is actually a bit confusing because of the way they decided to name things in the example, with 2 do_upload() functions. If you follow closely, you'll see your mistake

Comment: upvoted because after the RTFM scolding you showed how it could be confusing.

Comment: It wasn't a RTFM scolding, it was a "copy/paste from the FM correctly" scolding :-)